# Jira plugin not working with com.jcraft.jsch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

jcraft.jsch in my atlassian plugin in my webitem action it doesn't work and the button is not showen

**processGenerateClass.java**

```
public class processGenerateClass extends JiraWebActionSupport{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(processGenerateClass.class);


@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {

    return super.execute(); //returns SUCCESS
}

public void doRunCommand() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("*******************************************************");
    final String HOST = "*************";
    final String USERNAME = "*************";
    final String PASSWORD = "************";

    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    String[] commandes = { "5","log","subon","","JA002","","","","","","","","","Y"};

    System.out.println("Connexion");
    try {
        /**
         * Ouverture d'une session
         */
        Session session = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, HOST, 22);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        session.connect(30000);

        /**
         * Ouverture d'un channel pour executer les commandes
         */
        Channel channel = (Channel) session.openChannel("shell");

        OutputStream in = channel.getOutputStream();
        channel.connect(3 * 1000);

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        System.out.println("Ecriture");
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(in));

        for (int i = 0; i < commandes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("\nExecution de la commande ==> " + commandes[i]);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------");
            writer.write(commandes[i] + "\n");
            writer.flush();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("\n----------------------------------");
        }

        writer.close();
        in.close();
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erreur : " + e);
    }

    System.out.println("\nFin Connexion");  

}   }
```

**atlassian-plugin.xml**

```
<web-item name="Generate Process" key="generate-process" weight="20" section="transitions-all" i18n-name-key="generate-process.name">
<description key="generate-process.description">The generateprocess Plugin</description>
<label key="Generate Process"/>
<link linkId="generate-process-link">/secure/processGenerateClass!RunCommand.jspa</link>
```

The processGenerate Plugin
    
      
        /templates/process-generate/processgenerateclass/success.vm